# adding ImgeButton dynamically in scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

in my application i am adding image buttons in scroll view dynamically.but i am not able to view my image button.can anyone help.
here is my code--

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

scrollview=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
LinearLayout ll =( LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollinear);

ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);

button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.travel);

ll.addView(button);

setContentView(v);
```

here is my activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/scrollinear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFCC99"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout> 

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code

```
scrollview=(ScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
LinearLayout ll =( LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollinear);
```